# Error#1045 Access Denied in PhpMyAdmin with Xampp

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to get phpmyadmin up the access is simply denied when I try to use it with xampp. the following error code is given:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I have read related answers and tried to change the lines

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config' to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'`, but the this doesnt provide a solution. Any idea guys? I am using windows 7.

THIS IS THE CURRENT FILE:

```
* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'HTTP';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
```

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Link](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers) it might help you to resolve your problem.

```
1. Open config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory

2. Find line 21: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''

3. Change it to: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';

4. Restart XAMPP 


The setting you are looking for is "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']" - set this to 'HTTP', and you will be able to input a username and password.
```

Comment: hello i am a beginner, after step 5, where do you make the changes, isit in the SHELL command that comes with xampp?

Comment: if you do not have root password leave it blank or if you have root password paste your password in config.inc.php

Comment: its not helping, i have pasted my file above

Comment: any idea for error #1146.#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

Comment: You have to run the create_tables.sql inside the examples/ folder on phpMyAdmin to create the tables needed..